# Add listener on button in custom listview with MVC

Tags: listview, javafx, custom-controls

I've create a custom control that is a `list view` of my type "*`KMLFile`*", and each cell contains an `Hbox` of a `Label`, a `CheckBox`, and 2 `Button`.

Here's the code of how I do it :

Class that define `HBox` , `CellKML`:

```
public class CellKML {

    private KMLFile myKMLFile;
    private HBox cellHBox;
    private Label cellFileName;
    private CheckBox cellFileCheckBox;
    private Button cellFileRefresh;
    private Button cellFileClose;

    public CellKML(KMLFile kmlFile){
        this.myKMLFile = kmlFile;
    }

    public HBox createCell(){
        cellHBox = new HBox();
        cellFileName = new Label(myKMLFile.getFileName());
        cellFileCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        cellFileCheckBox.setSelected(true);
        cellFileRefresh = new Button("R");
        cellFileClose = new Button("X");

        cellHBox.getChildren().add(cellFileName);
        cellHBox.getChildren().add(cellFileCheckBox);
        cellHBox.getChildren().add(cellFileRefresh);
        cellHBox.getChildren().add(cellFileClose);



        return cellHBox;
    }
```

My `Custom ListView` is create in a classic *control/skin* class :

```
public class FileViewGridSkin extends SkinBase<FileViewGrid>{

    private FileViewGrid control;
    private ListView<KMLFile> listView;
    private boolean invalidListView = true;

    public FileViewGridSkin(FileViewGrid control) {
        super(control);
        this.control = control;        

    }

    public void createRootNode(){
        if(listView != null){
            getChildren().remove(listView);
        }

        listView = new ListView<KMLFile>();
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<KMLFile>, ListCell<KMLFile>>(){            
            @Override
            public ListCell<KMLFile> call(ListView<KMLFile> p) {

                ListCell<KMLFile> cell = new ListCell<KMLFile>(){

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(KMLFile kmlFile, boolean bln) {
                        super.updateItem(kmlFile, bln);
                        if (isEmpty()) {
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            if (kmlFile != null) {
                                CellKML cellKML = new CellKML(kmlFile);
                                setGraphic(cellKML.createCell());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                };

                return cell;
            }
        });
        listView.itemsProperty().bind(control.getList()); //Here bind the listview items to your control list
        getChildren().add(listView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double contentX, double contentY, double contentWidth, double contentHeight) {
        if(invalidListView){
            createRootNode();
            invalidListView = false;
        }
        layoutInArea(listView, contentX, contentY, contentWidth, contentHeight, -1,new Insets(1.0), HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);

    }

    public ListView<KMLFile> getListView() {
        return listView;
    }
```

My goal is to **add a listener** on the `CheckBox` and the 2 `Button` that will interact with the "`KMLFile`". *I could do it easily in my class `CellKML`*, but I'm in a **MVC pattern**, I can't put control in my *View*.

So I put in place a *Controller* that have access to my `ListView`, but I don't *know how to have access* to my CheckBox and Button, for setting listener.

Comment: One way can be sending the **eventHandlers** (not the logic itself) to createCell() as parameter. These eventHandlers will come from control class.

Comment: With this solution I don't have acces to my component from outside ... I was thinking of putting in place an event handler on my list view and every time a cell is created I put my listener on my component.